# Powershell Test-Path in foreach loop null

Tags: powershell

I have a list of numbers in a file (123-45-678, 876-54-321, but they're on separate lines) and I'm trying to do something if a number is in the file and something else if it is not.

```
$list = Get-Content $env:USERPROFILE\Documents\list.txt

Foreach ($obj in $list) 
{
  $nxt = Get-ChildItem -Path $env:USERPROFILE\Documents\files -Recurse -Filter "*$obj*"
  $FileExists = Test-Path $nxt
  If ($FileExists -ne $True) 
  {
    Write-Host "Yippee"
  }  
  Else
  {
    Write-Host "Not found"
  }
}
```

If there is a number in the file it seems to work but if it's not I get the following

```
TEST-PATH : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is null.
```

I thought the purpose of test-path was to return something if it couldn't find anything?

Comment: `Test-Path` can only return something if you give it something to test. The variable `$nxt` is empty because probably your filter option does not work as expected.

Comment: The folder it's looking in has 2 word documents with the filenames being the 2 I posted. If I put a third number in the list and that file is not in the folder it gives that error.

Comment: Because the filter is then "**" which is probably not among the file names. Just run your `$nxt` line with this filter and see what the variable contains.

Comment: 1. What is in list.txt, 2. You are checking to see if the file **does not exist**, (`-ne $true`) is this intended? 3. Try using `-include` instead of `-filter`

Comment: I took out the wildcards and it gives the same error. List.txt is a list of numbers on separate lines. It's supposed to check if it does exist. The "-ne" was a leftover part when I was testing and I forgot to put it back.

Comment: So the `-ne` should either be `-ne $false` or `-eq $True` correct?

Comment: That's correct. I tried it a different way and I don't get an error but it just keeps saying "It is found" even though I know it's not true using 

`$list = Get-Content $env:USERPROFILE\Documents\list.txt


Foreach ($obj in $list) {
$nxt = Get-ChildItem -Path $env:USERPROFILE\Documents\files -Recurse -Filter "*$obj*"
if([System.IO.File]::Exists($nxt)){
    Write-Host "Not found"
}

#Copy-Item "$nxt" -destination "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\merge"
Else {Write-Host "It is found"}
}`

Answer (score 0):

Why are you negating the results of both `Test-Path` and `if([System.IO.File]::Exists($nxt))` ?
If either returns `$true`, then the file **EXISTS**.

Because you say you want to do something if a file with any such number in its name is found and something else if not, I would do it using the regular expression `-match` operator.
For that, you need to put all possible numbers from the text file in a single string, separated by the regex OR operator `|`:

```
# get the numbers from the file and for security remove empty or whitespace-only lines
$list  = Get-Content -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\list.txt" | Where-Object { $_ -match '\S' } 

# build a regex string from that array
$regex = ($list | ForEach-Object { [regex]::Escape($_) }) -join '|'

# get all files and test if they match any of the numbers
Get-ChildItem -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\Documents\files" -Recurse -File | ForEach-Object {
    if ( $_.Name -match $regex ) {
        Write-Host "File '$($_.Name)' exists" -ForegroundColor Green
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "File '$($_.FullName)' does not match any of the items in the list."
    }
}
```

Result would look something like this:

```
File '876-54-321.txt' exists
File 'C:\snowman\Documents\files\somefile.txt' does not match any of the items in the list.
File 'Whatever 123-45-678-901.txt' exists
File 'XYZ 876-54-321.txt' exists
```